# distcp java api exit the application

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i need to copy files between aws s3 and our local hdfs, i tried to use distcp java api but the problem with it is at the end of distcp it called System.exit(), which stopped my app too, so if i have multiple folders/files to copy and i used multiple threads, each thread perform a distcp command, the first thread who finish the distcp will stop the app, thus stop the rest of distcp, is there any other way to avoid this, i know i can write up my own MR job to do the copied but want to know if there other options

my code:

```
List<Future<Void>> calls = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();       
for (String dir : s3Dirs) {
    final String[] args = new String[4];
    args[0] = "-log";   
    args[1] = LOG_DIR;
    args[2] = S3_DIR;
    args[3] = LOCAL_HDFS_DIR

    calls.add(_exec.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
       @Override
       public Void call() throws Exception {                
         try {
        DistCp.main(args);      <-- Distcp command          
         } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to copy files from " + args[2] + " to " + args[3]);
         }
         return null;
    }
    }));            
}

for (Future<Void> f : calls) {
    try {
        f.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while distcp", e);
    }   
}
```

Distcp main()

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {

        int exitCode;
        try {
          DistCp distCp = new DistCp();
          Cleanup CLEANUP = new Cleanup(distCp);

          ShutdownHookManager.get().addShutdownHook(CLEANUP,
            SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY);
          exitCode = ToolRunner.run(getDefaultConf(), distCp, argv);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          LOG.error("Couldn't complete DistCp operation: ", e);
          exitCode = DistCpConstants.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
        }
        System.exit(exitCode);        <--- exit here
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used distcp before and never faced the System.exit() problem, even with multiple threads. Try, instead of using the Distcp like that, using the ToolRunner to invoke a distcp call(like it is used [on the Distcp Test cases from the hadoop tools package](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp)). The Distcp Test cases use the ToolRunner to run distcp and it allows you to run it with multiple threads. I am copying the code snippet from the above link here:

```
public void testCopyFromLocalToLocal() throws Exception {
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  FileSystem localfs = FileSystem.get(LOCAL_FS, conf);
  MyFile[] files = createFiles(LOCAL_FS, TEST_ROOT_DIR+"/srcdat");
  ToolRunner.run(new DistCp(new Configuration()),
                         new String[] {"file:///"+TEST_ROOT_DIR+"/srcdat",
                                       "file:///"+TEST_ROOT_DIR+"/destdat"});
  assertTrue("Source and destination directories do not match.",
             checkFiles(localfs, TEST_ROOT_DIR+"/destdat", files));
  deldir(localfs, TEST_ROOT_DIR+"/destdat");
  deldir(localfs, TEST_ROOT_DIR+"/srcdat");
}
```

Comment: Please include some of the information from your link in your answer. If the link goes away in the future, this answer won't really help.

Comment: It actually answers the "want to know other options". I don't think he really wanted to solve the System.exit problem, but to copy the files from a cluster to the other. If it solves his problem, why is it not a valid answer?